# Is it safe to return local CStringW to the caller?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, cstring

I have a function defined a local variable typed in CStringW, is it safe to return this object to the caller by value, not by reference?

Comment: The converse is actually what's not safe; don't return a reference to a local variable because when it gets out of scope your reference is dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be ok. `CString` internally uses a buffer with reference counting and does copy-on-write, so that when you create a copy of `CString` and then destroy the original object, everything should "just work".

Answer (score 1):

I believe CString is from MFC, not STL, so you might want to change your tags.

If you're returning a local variable from a function, it's safe to return by value, but *not* safe to return by reference.  Returning by value effectively copies the string to the caller.  Returning by reference gives the caller a reference to the local variable which is destroyed when the function returns - so the caller can never use it, and the returned reference is always invalid.